# Summation of a list using eval

Tags: python, list, eval

I have a list like this

```
yy = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']
```

with the values for `A1`, `B1` and `C1` in a dict like this

```
ff = {
    'A1': 10,
    'B1': 20,
    'C1': 30
}
```

Now I want to do sum of the list with values from `ff`. This is what I tried to do

```
p = "sum(lst)"

eval(p, {'lst': yy}, ff)
```

But I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`.
During debugging I found out that if I do like this `p = "sum([A1, B1, C1])"` and eval It works. Not sure why this happens?

Full code:

```
ff = {
    'A1': 10,
    'B1': 20,
    'C1': 30
}


yy = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']

p = "sum(lst)"

eval(p, {'lst': yy}, ff)
```

I know `eval`'s consequences. I filter everything before it reaches `eval`

Comment: Explain why you need eval. You need a **good** reason to use eval. Simply put: don't use eval.

Comment: I am  using eval to parse Excel formulas like this one `'=SUM(AY92:BI92)/SUM(AL92:AX92)'` where I first expand the list from Ay92 to BI92 and then do a sum using eval.

Comment: I do kinda understand your problem here. Are you trying to meddle with `eval`'s optional params to get your output?

Comment: Using eval on something what looks like (user generated?) input is bad. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice?lq=1). I could make Excel formula that would mess up my computer. And worse any computer that runs your script on my formula.

Comment: I cannot get those values. see my full code here http://pastebin.com/RSHZN4vq

Comment: I know its consequences. I filter everything before it reaches eval(). so no worries.

Comment: Yes THIS is what I want. I just need to remove those quotes. I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: I can't comment on you code in this small comment, I suggest that after having a working code (using `eval` or whatnot) you post it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and get a way to make it work without using `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though this is not advised you can try

```
ff = {
    'A1': 10,
    'B1': 20,
    'C1': 30
}


yy = '[A1, B1, C1]'

p = "sum(eval(lst))"

eval(p, {'lst': yy}, ff)
```

The working of this is

- The first `eval` call will convert the variable `lst` and do

  ```
  sum(eval('[A1, B1, C1]'))
  ```
- The second `eval` will now convert the inner variables and make it as

  ```
  sum([10, 20, 30])
  ```

This will give you your output.

Also note that if you are unable to initialize the variable `yy`, you can use the [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) function

```
yy = str(yy).replace("'", '')
```

This will return `'[A1, B1, C1]'` from your earlier variable.

Comment: you can use `yy = str(yy).replace("'", '')` instead of hardcoding it to `yy = '[A1, B1, C1]'`

Comment: @f.rodrigues True. But do see the difference. When you type out `['A1', 'B1', 'C1']` you will have to add `'` everywhere except at the ends and then the additional overhead of `replace`. However if the OP is getting the list like that itself from the other end, then your advise of using `replace` is certainly the way to go. I have added it as a note below

Comment: Exactly, If he can initialize `yy` the way he wants, your answer is fine and a lot cleaner, I was assuming he could, like using `ff.keys()` would yield `['A1', 'B1', 'C1']` anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have to use [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)?

why not use `sum()`;

```
yy = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']

ff = {
    'A1': 10,
    'B1': 20,
    'C1': 30
}

print sum([ff[key] for key in yy])
```

if you really need to use `eval`, here how to do it:

```
print eval('+'.join(str(ff[key]) for key in yy))
# or for short
print eval("+".join(yy), globals=ff)

# or the way you are doing
print eval("sum(lst)", {'lst': [ff[key] for key in yy]})
```

The reason you were getting a `TypeError` is because `"sum(lst)"` is essently `sum(['A1', 'B1', 'C1'])`, which Python doesn't know how to handle. By changing `lst` to `[ff[key] for key in yy]` we are making a new list that's of the number referenced(by key) by `yy` in `ff`

I see your comment:

> I am using eval to parse Excel formulas like this one '=SUM(AY92:BI92)/SUM(AL92:AX92)' where I first expand the list from Ay92 to BI92 and then do a sum using eval

Why not get the values of `AY92:BI92` into a list and the values of `AL92:AX92` into a second list and them use `sum(lst1)/sum(lst2)`? Eval is nasty, if this excel file contains malicious code inside the cell, it will be run.

Comment: I need to do this by using eval()

Comment: I would like to expand on f.rodrigues's answer here. When you do `eval(p, {'lst': yy}, ff)` as the OP has done, it does `sum(lst)` which is `sum(['A1', 'B1', 'C1'])` for which it returns the `TypeError`

Comment: How to remove those brackets across A1 and so on? that would do.

Comment: It would throw a `NameError` since you haven't defined what `A1` is.

Answer (score 0):

Given that data to sum up the elements in the dictionary that are referred to by the strings in the list:

```
yy = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']
ff = {
    'A1': 10,
    'B1': 20,
    'C1': 30
}
print (sum(map(ff.get, yy)))
```

`ff.get` returns the value of a given key. Map that across the list giving a list of numbers which is then given to `sum`.

See:

```
>>> print (sum(map(ff.get, yy)))
60
```

If you must `eval`:

```
>>> eval("sum(map(tab.get, lst))", {'lst': yy, 'tab': ff})
60
```

Comment: I need to do this by using eval()

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straighforward:

```
>>> yy = ['A1', 'B1', 'C1']
>>> ff = {
...     'A1': 10,
...     'B1': 20,
...     'C1': 30
... }
>>> sum(ff[i] for i in yy)
60
```

But, if you somehow need to use eval (I don't know why).

```
>>> eval("+".join(yy), ff)
60
```

But, really there's no reason to use `eval` for this. It is neither fast nor secure.